# Embed FinderSync Extension appex to Electron app

Tags: swift, xcode, electron, finder, macos-app-extension

I have build an electron app to sync files with selected directories and a FinderSync extension to show the sync status of the files and show contextual menus.

The extension is working well with a main app, but when i embed the extension in the electron app, the FinderSync extension doesn't run. I've checked the console and the running processes but i don't find the extension process, so i think i have to embed the extension in another way.

I have done it this way: [How to embed a mac app extension in an Electron app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45612515/how-to-embed-a-mac-app-extension-in-an-electron-app/48942130#48942130)

There's the mac object key of the project:

```
"mac": {
   "category": "public.app-category.productivity",
   "darkModeSupport": true,
   "hardenedRuntime": true,
   "gatekeeperAssess": false,
   "target": "dmg",
   "type": "development",
   "entitlements": "./build-files/mac/entitlements.mac.inherit.plist",
   "entitlementsInherit": "./build-files/mac/entitlements.mac.inherit.plist",
   "extraFiles": [
     "PlugIns/"
   ],
   "extraDistFiles": [
     "PlugIns/"
   ]
 },
```

Any idea about what am i doing wrong or how i have to do it?

Comment: @marco-moschettini how do you solved?